# Flutter HTTP Get Request Wrong Port

Tags: dart, flutter

i try to perform a GET request to my localhost server. i run the flutter application on a external device with android studio and the XAMPP/php server with the endpoint run on the pc too. now is the problem every time i run the GET request it run on a wrong port. i write in the url port 80 but flutter perform it on 53555 or other 53... 
i try to change the url but nothing changed.
here is the code and the error message

```
var url = new Uri.http("192.168.2.23:80", "/login", {"username":username,"password":password});
print(url);
var client = http.Client();
http.Response response = await client.get(url);

print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

this is the error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 192.168.2.23, port = 53695
```

Comment: If you are running the app on an Android emulator you'll probably need a port forwarding for the emulator.

Comment: Because the 53... port is the *local* port. The one used by your OS. The `80` port is the *target* port.

Comment: and how i can setup the 80 port for the emulator ?